# UIWebView: Change URL Based On What Cell Selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have tableView with 3 cells.  When user clicks cell, it pushes to a webViewController.

in webViewController's viewDidLoad i have:

```
    //A URL STRING
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";

    //Create a URL object FROM THAT STRING
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object CREATD FROM YOUR URL OBJECT
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [wView loadRequest:requestObj];

    //scale the page to the device - This can also be done in IB if you prefer
    wView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

My question is, how can I change the urlAddress based on what cell the user clicked to get to this view?

Like if they selected cell at indexPath.row == 0, then load google.com, index.row == 1, load facebook.com, etc.

Comment: Pass a variable from parent view (table view ) to web view. for example : in tableview  objwebview.url =@"www.google.com"; [self.view addsubview objwebview.view]; thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do the job in this method, which is to detect the row is being selected or not.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 //do your webviewcontroller declaration here.
 WebViewController *wvc = [WebViewController alloc] initWithNib ...];

 if(indexPath.row == 0){
   wvc.urlAddress = @"http://google.com";
 }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
   wvc.urlAddress = @"http://facebook.com";
 }else{
   wvc.urlAddress = @"http://abc.com";
 }
//then open that view here...
}
```

make sure you able to access the urlAddress, and property and synthesize in webviewcontroller.h.

ok assume you have a WebViewController class, in it header file.

```
//WebViewController.h
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *urlAddress;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *urlAddress;

@end

//WebViewController.m
@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize urlAddress;
//... example ...
@end
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `property type "urlAddress" not found on object of type "WebViewController"`.

Comment: do you declare it in your webviewController class?

Comment: yup, declared it and added property: `@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *urlAddress;`.  Do I have to do `@class WebViewController` in my other view Controller?

Comment: the urlAddress must declare inside the WebViewController and not the current view. and of course your current view (which your tableView locate) must import that WebViewController in the top.

Comment: Yes I have done, all that. I have #import "WebViewController.h".

Comment: I think the format of `wvc.urlAddress = @"http://google.com";` may be causing the problem.

Comment: nop it should be fine. because that line mean it pass the string value to the urlAddress in wvc class (WebViewController).

Comment: can you post the code snipper on how you call to the webviewcontroller?

Comment: Ok got it, I did `WebViewController *detailViewController` so I had to use detailViewController.urlAddress.

Comment: It really that line cause the problem - -', but anyway glad it working.